# Is it okay to refer to a certain period of time in the past when we speak about a fact that is still true today?

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to refer to a certain period of time in the past when we speak about a fact that is still true today?

For example:

"This idea **has for a long time been** one of the central topics of debate in philosophy, **especially from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries.**"

How can I rewrite my sentence to say that although the idea is still a central topic of debate in philosophy, it was "more central" (and more discussed) from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries?

Comment: Sure. The part about the specific period is just additional emphasis.

Comment: You need to hear from someone else, but I'll chime in on the sentences you added at the end of your question. The first sentence implies that the idea has been a central topic of debate for a long time, up to and including the present. The second sentence implies it was a central topic only within a prescribed window of time that does not include the present. Contradictory.

Comment: I do think there is something wrong there. You can see it more clearly it by simplifying the sentence: *This idea has always been a central topic, especially in the 19th century. --> This idea has always been a central topic in the 19th century.* Try: *This idea has always been a central topic—and was especially so in the 19th century.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat: The only thing wrong there is that the time references are too far apart for comfort. In other words, the writing is a bit flabby. Better would be: "For a long time, and especially from the early 19th to the mid-20th century, this idea has been one of the central topics of debate in philosophy."

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence as written implies that the idea is still a **central** topic of debate today, but not the **central** topic it was from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries. Given that this seems at least slightly contradictory, I would consider revising it as follows:

> "This idea has for a long time been a topic of debate in philosophy, especially from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries."

This revised sentence implies that the idea is still a topic of debate today but not does not command the same ("central") attention it had from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries. If you want to maintain your emphasis on **central**, you could write:

> "This idea *was* a central topic of debate in philosophy from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries."

This does not imply that it wasn't a topic of debate earlier or later, only that it was not a **central** topic. In this second rewrite, *for a long time* is implicit in, and communicated precisely by, *from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries*.

Comment: But why do you think that my sentence does not imply that the idea was a central topic of debate "especially from the early 19th..."? How is it contradictory?

Comment: @pip321 If we remove *especially from the early 19th to the mid-20th centuries*, your sentence reads: "This idea has for a long time been one of the central topics of debate in philosophy." This implies that it remains a central topic of debate today. However, "especially from the early 19th to mid-20th centuries" in your original sentence implies to me that it is no longer a central topic of debate, that that status ended in the mid-20th century. This is what I said seemed at least slightly contradictory. Is the idea a central topic of debate today or not? I hope this helps.